# Did not find value which can be converted into java.lang.String

Tags: json, scala, hbase

I have a JSON input which is to be written into Hbase

an example of this is

```
 {
  "contributors": null,
  "truncated": false,
  "text": "#Care #MichelleNunn #Stop #Pimping #Haiti #HurricaneMatthew #Give #Answers #Blacklivesmatter https:\/\/t.co\/mmlOawLdCy",
  "is_quote_status": false,
  "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
  "id": 8.4878269282513e+17,
  "favorite_count": 0,
  "entities": {
    "symbols": [

    ],
    "user_mentions": [

    ],
    "hashtags": [
      {
        "indices": [
          0,
          5
        ],
        "text": "Care"
      },
      {
        "indices": [
          6,
          19
        ],
        "text": "MichelleNunn"
      },
      {
        "indices": [
          20,
          25
        ],
        "text": "Stop"
      },
      {
        "indices": [
          26,
          34
        ],
        "text": "Pimping"
      },
      {
        "indices": [
          35,
          41
        ],
        "text": "Haiti"
      },
      {
        "indices": [
          42,
          59
        ],
        "text": "HurricaneMatthew"
      },
      {
        "indices": [
          60,
          65
        ],
        "text": "Give"
      },
      {
        "indices": [
          66,
          74
        ],
        "text": "Answers"
      },
      {
        "indices": [
          75,
          92
        ],
        "text": "Blacklivesmatter"
      }
    ],
    "urls": [

    ],
    "media": [
      {
        "expanded_url": "https:\/\/twitter.com\/skri_ar\/status\/848782692825128961\/photo\/1",
        "display_url": "pic.twitter.com\/mmlOawLdCy",
        "url": "https:\/\/t.co\/mmlOawLdCy",
        "media_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/C8d7XE2XsAAiIsY.jpg",
        "id_str": "848782691151622144",
        "sizes": {
          "large": {
            "h": 618,
            "resize": "fit",
            "w": 986
          },
          "small": {
            "h": 426,
            "resize": "fit",
            "w": 680
          },
          "medium": {
            "h": 618,
            "resize": "fit",
            "w": 986
          },
          "thumb": {
            "h": 150,
            "resize": "crop",
            "w": 150
          }
        },
        "indices": [
          93,
          116
        ],
        "type": "photo",
        "id": 8.4878269115162e+17,
        "media_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/C8d7XE2XsAAiIsY.jpg"
      }
    ]
  },
  "retweeted": false,
  "coordinates": null,
  "source": "<a href=\"https:\/\/ifttt.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">IFTTT<\/a>",
  "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
  "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
  "retweet_count": 0,
  "id_str": "848782692825128961",
  "favorited": false,
  "user": {
    "follow_request_sent": false,
    "has_extended_profile": false,
    "profile_use_background_image": true,
    "default_profile_image": false,
    "id": 7.8840475360896e+17,
    "profile_background_image_url_https": null,
    "verified": false,
    "translator_type": "none",
    "profile_text_color": "333333",
    "profile_image_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/788412708530061313\/gqwMR-0g_normal.jpg",
    "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6",
    "entities": {
      "description": {
        "urls": [

        ]
      }
    },
    "followers_count": 15,
    "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED",
    "id_str": "788404753608957956",
    "profile_background_color": "F5F8FA",
    "listed_count": 15,
    "is_translation_enabled": false,
    "utc_offset": null,
    "statuses_count": 25793,
    "description": "",
    "friends_count": 0,
    "location": "",
    "profile_link_color": "1DA1F2",
    "profile_image_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/788412708530061313\/gqwMR-0g_normal.jpg",
    "following": false,
    "geo_enabled": false,
    "profile_banner_url": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/788404753608957956\/1476807236",
    "profile_background_image_url": null,
    "screen_name": "skri_ar",
    "lang": "en",
    "profile_background_tile": false,
    "favourites_count": 0,
    "name": "Ar Skri",
    "notifications": false,
    "url": null,
    "created_at": "Tue Oct 18 15:41:56 +0000 2016",
    "contributors_enabled": false,
    "time_zone": null,
    "protected": false,
    "default_profile": true,
    "is_translator": false
  },
  "geo": null,
  "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
  "possibly_sensitive": false,
  "lang": "und",
  "created_at": "Mon Apr 03 06:22:18 +0000 2017",
  "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
  "place": null,
  "extended_entities": {
    "media": [
      {
        "expanded_url": "https:\/\/twitter.com\/skri_ar\/status\/848782692825128961\/photo\/1",
        "display_url": "pic.twitter.com\/mmlOawLdCy",
        "url": "https:\/\/t.co\/mmlOawLdCy",
        "media_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/C8d7XE2XsAAiIsY.jpg",
        "id_str": "848782691151622144",
        "sizes": {
          "large": {
            "h": 618,
            "resize": "fit",
            "w": 986
          },
          "small": {
            "h": 426,
            "resize": "fit",
            "w": 680
          },
          "medium": {
            "h": 618,
            "resize": "fit",
            "w": 986
          },
          "thumb": {
            "h": 150,
            "resize": "crop",
            "w": 150
          }
        },
        "indices": [
          93,
          116
        ],
        "type": "photo",
        "id": 8.4878269115162e+17,
        "media_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/C8d7XE2XsAAiIsY.jpg"
      }
    ]
  },
  "metadata": {
    "iso_language_code": "und",
    "result_type": "recent"
  }
}
```

Now I wrote a scala script which takes in the individual values and stores it into Hbase.However with the "text" value it is throwing a error like `org.json4s.package$MappingException: Did not find value which can be converted into java.lang.String`

The scala script which parses the JSON file is as follows:

```
def parse_json(json_string: String, collection_name: String, collection_Id: String ):(ImmutableBytesWritable, Put) = {

    val json_object = parse(json_string)
    //printIn(json_object)
    val id = (json_object \ "id_str").extract[String]
    val favorite_count = (json_object \ "favorite_count").extract[String]
    val retweet_count = (json_object \ "retweet_count").extract[String]
    val text = (json_object \ "text").extract[String]
put.add(Bytes.toBytes("tweet"),Bytes.toBytes("text"), Bytes.toBytes(text))
```

Please help me in resolving this error as all the other fields are properly inserted into HBase if I comment the text line

Comment: Ram, the issue is not reprorducible witht the data you provided so I suspect that the data is the culprit. Wrap your `parse_json` in `try`/`catch` and log actual `json_string` when the parsing fails. I bet there will be no `"text"` in it. P.S. also it helps to explicitly mention the libary you use for JSON parsing in the question and/or in the tags as in the Scala world there are a few choices. No we have to deduce it by the exception package.

Comment: @SergGr Even I am thinking it might be the issue.So can I replace the empty string with a default value?like using getOrElse.Could you please provide me an example of how to do modify val text line to get this.I am newbie to Scala so kindly excuse me for this

Comment: Never mind was able to add a default value.Thanks a lot@SergGr

Answer (score 0):

Best `extract[]` with the type exactly as in the JSON. If you need a different type you can still convert it. See that `favorite_count` is an Int (no quotes) :

```
  "favorite_count": 0,
...
  "retweet_count": 0,
```

so best use

```
val favorite_count = (json_object \ "favorite_count").extract[Int]
val retweet_count = (json_object \ "retweet_count").extract[Int]
```

or if you actually need them to be a String add  `.toString`

Hope this helps.
And adding a `try / catch` is always a good idea, as suggested by @SergGr .